# How to transfer Weights from one to another object with rigify

Tags: rigify

I have rigged my 1st object with rigify, weight painted it. Then I had update on mesh, because now I have jersey on it, and mesh under the jersey is deleted. However, similiar weight paint and rig should work.
Now I can't generate that metarig to new object, because when I try to "Re-Generate rig" it always renegenerate to the original ( old ) one. I tried to apply location, but always it's the old one. Only way I managed to generate new rig to the new object is to delete old one rig and object, however that makes it impossible to copy the weight painting to the new one.
I tried with methods I found online, but they are all with armature which was not made by rigify.
[image]
Left one, rigged and painted.

Comment: Assuming the left and right dogs are "twins"...  I might duplicate all on the left, add the jersey over it, and use some Mask modifier over the dog's body under the jersey (so that it never show through).  I would then either parent the jersey to *that* rig, or I might just SurfaceDeform (modifier) the jersey to the dogs body (don't have to use Mask as it body would never show through). It will be a larger file with more (unseen) vertices, but I often do this for ease of rigging.

Comment: Also, I might link the dog from a separate file with multiple jeysey's or color custom properties (color, number), and then enable/disable rendering of the jersey as needed.  I have done this for characters where twins might have different color eyes, color cloths, different hair-styles, enable render of various shirts/pants.  You can also have some animation actions that you can then combine, re-time, mix in NLA.

Comment: If you want to transfer the weights from the dog to the jersey just move the jersey to the dog at the same spot. Select the dog, then the jersey. The dog should be red (=selected object=target) and the jersey should be orange (=active object=source). Then use the menu *Object > Link/Transfer Data (Ctrl+L) > Transfer Mesh Data*. In the popup select *Vertex Group(s)* where the weights are stored. In the next popup select *All Layers* and make sure *Data Type* is *Vertex Group(s)*. If you use the shortcut Ctrl+L only the 2nd popup will appear. Dismiss the popup & the weights should be transferred

Comment: If you want to create a 2nd Rigify animation rig you need to change the name of the generated rig. Otherwise, it will re-create an existing rig. Below the "Re-generate Rig" button there is a section called "Advanced". If you expand it, you can change the name for the Target Rig and the Rig UI Script. Change both, the script has a unique id in it, not sure if it works for 2 different rigs. Re-/Generating the rig will not change the weights.

Comment: Usefull, thank you for time. Anyway I figure out that I messed the head rig because you are not supposed to remove any facial bones, so I need to go from beginning. Thanks!